# Can't acess shared files on win7 from win8

Tags: windows-8

I have PC with win7 and it is sharing a public folder.
I have two laptops - one with win7 and one with win8 (new one).

From laptop with win7 I can go to Network->My PC->public (public is shared folder).
From laptop with win8 I can go to Network->My PC. Inside My PC I can see folder 'public' but when I click it there is error like this:

`Network error - you don't have permissions to access this resource (\\Network\\My PC\public)`

I am not using any HomeGroup. What I have to do to access this folder from my win8 laptop?

edit --------

I forgot to mention that win8 laptop has access to win7 laptop and even other laptops with xp

Comment: You should be using HomeGroup it will solve the permission problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will be wanting to grant the user object "Everyone" access to the share. To do so, head to your Windows 7 laptop, right click the folder, go to "Share with" and click "Specific people...". Here you type in "Everyone" and click add.

Remember to allow write-access underneath if you need that.